# Ubuntu 11.10 Server remote access

Tags: 11.10, server, password, remote-access

A IT Tech person set us up a Ubuntu Server 11.10 fileserver is there a way that you can remote access the file on the server, I know that it can me done but I'm not sure if it have been setup. how to you know if it has been setup & how to access it. & is there a way reset the username & Password as the IT tech didn't tell use this information & if I call him back out to have a look at it, he will charge us $100 an hour.

Answer (score 0):

If a ssh-server has been installed on your server (most of the time a ssh server is installed on servers) you can access it using ssh command.

```
ssh urusername@urserverip
```

If you can access it using ssh you can change your password or add a new user (You can do all the administration work).